# Exercised an option got the stock less a thousand dollars

Tags: options

The stock price is $19.00 per share.

I bought a call, and the strike price $7.50 for a premium of $7.90, at the bottom before I submit it, read

> "you are paying $790 the right to buy …. At a $7.50 per share on Feb
> 2, 2024 …… if the stock is $7.50 or higher .etc etc “.

So I realized it, if I exercise the next day, since it’s higher (stock price) more than my strike price ($7.50). So I have the right to buy a stock, at closing was $19.60 per share.

I did exercise the next day, and before doing so there were several question why was I exercising.

- The first was like if it's out of the money and you’re losing.
- The second was like cancelling or somewhat.
- And the third was simply “buy the stock“ on this platform I’m using.

So I did exercise and got it at $790. Instead of me buying it at $1960 for 100 shares. Knowingly I took someone’s stock for a low price.

Am I a bad person, or it’s a risk everyone should be aware of. I truly realized this, when I was selling a call and someone got my stock at the strike price even for it expired. You think it’s exactly the same as my question, the situation I experienced too.

Is it illegal ? is my question.

Comment: You are asking if it is illegal to make money in the stock market?

Comment: I don't think you got it for $790. You paid $790 for the premium (e.g. the right to buy at $7.50), and an additional $750 to actually buy (which of course would still be a nice profit from $1540 to $1960). Did you buy the options one day before? In that case, unless the stock made a big jump after you bought the options, you might have missed some costs or conditions (which is maybe why the warning about being out of money did appear), as the premium plus strike one day earlier should have been close to the stock price.

Comment: You should really do a lot more homework before playing with the stock market, especially options.

Comment: You've exercised your TU $7.50
Call 2/16 contract in your brokerage account.
You were credited 100 shares of TU.
You were debited an amount of $750.00.
You bought 100 shares of TU in your brokerage account because of a recent option event.
6:18 AM Yay!
Your order to buy to
open 1 contract of TU $7.50 Call 2/16 in your brokerage account has been filled at an average price of $1,090.00 per contract.
Your order is complete.
View Order
Feb 2 at 6:18 AM
You've exercised your TU $7.50
Call 2/16 contract in your brokerage account.

Comment: Yay!
Your order to buy to
open 1 contract of TU $7.50 Call 2/16 in your brokerage account has been filled at an average price of $1,090.00 per contract.
Your order is complete.
View Order
Feb 2 at 6:18 AM
You've exercised your TU $7.50
Call 2/16 contract in your brokerage account.
You were credited 100 shares of TU.
You were debited an amount of $750.00.. The continuation of it

Comment: According to your quote, the premium was 10.90, not 7.90, so including the strike of 7.50 that is a price of 18.40 per share. If TU is "Telus Corp", they closed on Feb 1st at 18.12 (which could fit your option price - strike plus premium slightly above the current stock price). It closed on Feb 2nd at 17.71 (which could explain the out of money warning - although of course it wouldn't make sense not to exercise). You might want to recheck your stock and price data.

Comment: My bad , I came to realize everything was equivalent to what the stock price was . I got confused , but that’s how I learn . Thanks though . I paid $1090 for the right to buy 100 shares at $7.50 though the stock price is $17.75  or something . So it was a right to buy at $7.50 of a 100 shares which is $750 plus my premium if $1090 also adds up to $17.85 or something . So it’s almost the same . Right ?  I thought doing options can give you leverage if you  don’t have much capital to buy , options can help . Example of which is $150 ABC stock price . With options , one ca. buy - contract ex.

Comment: Anyway me nobody , thanks for your comment . I need to study more thanks again.

Comment: To clarify: $750 + $1090 is $1840, not $1785, so you overpaid by around $60 - but still have the chance that the stock goes up, as well as the risk of it going down further. Nevertheless it was correct to exercise, as you only lost (for now) around $60, instead of your whole premium of $1090 if you don't exercise (and are left with no stocks or options).

Answer (score 1):

> Knowingly I took someone’s stock for a low price.

No, you exercised a contract with another person who first *received* $790 for taking the risk of someone buying their shares for $750. So they get a "guaranteed" $1960 in exchange for the opportunity costs if the stock went higher (which it did).

If the stock had gone down, obviously you would have lost money if you had exercised, and the other side would have received a better deal than they would if they sold the stock at the lower price.

nothing illegal or immoral about it.

-- EDIT --

After looking more closely, there's no way that you bought $7.50 calls on a $19.00 stock for $7.90. Calls that deep in-the-money would have been priced at $11.50 or slightly higher. Either the price of the stock when you bought the calls was must lower or the price you paid was much hugher.

In either case, the answer still holds. Yes you made money on that individual trade, and whoever was on the other side lost money, just not as much as you think when you include the premium you paid.

Comment: Ok guys thank you for the answers . I will post again a screenshot

Comment: Just saying: As long as the share price is above $7.50 buying the options may have been a bad idea, and you may be losing money overall, but exercising the option will reduce your loss.

Comment: Thank you my bad , I’m just confused , probably I will learn the hard way but thanks though